# Find the residue of the function $\frac {1} {z^3-z^5}$ in $z = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the residues of the function $\frac {1} {z^3-z^5}$ at all their isolated singularities and at infinity (if it is not the limit of singularities).

All isolated singular points are $ z= -1$, $z = 0$ and $z = 1$. I have already found the residues in these points but my questions are:

How do I know that the residue can be calculated with respect to the infinite point?

How do I know that $z = \infty$  is not a limit of singular points?

How do I find the residue with respect to $z = \infty$?

Comment: Broad hints: you know that your function has only a finite number of singularities, so $z=\infty$ can't be a limit of singular points.  To calculate the residue at infinity, note that $f(z) = z^{-3}(\frac1{1-z^2})$; consider writing $f$ as a function $g(w)$, where $w=z^{-1}$. Then the residue of $f$ at $\infty$ can be computed in terms of the residue of $g$ at $0$...

Comment: The residue is a property of the 1-form $f(z)dz$. Thus changing variables $z=1/w$ leads to $-w^{-2}f(1/w)dw$, which is also what is written in the answer of RobertZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. In general, the residue of $f$ which is holomorphic in $|z|>R$ is defined as
$$-\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{f(1/z)}{z^2},0\right).$$
Moreover note that the sum of all residues of a rational function is equal to zero.